# Re-displaying html input range thumb in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I am building a page where I want to get user input in a range, but I don't want to bias the user with a default value beforehand. What I am therefore trying to do is have an input range slider that by default has a class that has styling to hide the thumb, then using an `onchange` event for the slider, remove the class so that the thumb shows up again.

The odd behavior I'm running into is that this works in Safari, but not Chrome (currently only using webkit). Everything seems to be updating correctly (e.g., the class gets changed, and the css styling only works with that class name applied), but when the class is removed the thumb remains hidden in Chrome. I'm using v55.0.2883.95 for Mac if that makes any difference.

Is there any way to force the slider element to re-check its class and add the slider thumb back?

A minimal working example is below:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
input[type=range].drange::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
</style>
</head>

<script>
function onchg() {
    var s = document.getElementById('slider');
    s.className = "";
    console.log('Changed!');
};
</script>

<body>
    <input id="slider" class="drange" type="range" min="0" max="100" default="50" onchange="onchg();"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this is a bug in chrome tbh. Do you know what's the default value for appearance ?

Comment: please accept and upvote :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a bug, but I found a fix after a long time:

```
.drange2::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: initial;
        background: black;
}
```

just add a background color to the thumb when you wanna show it. The reason it didn't show is because it was transparent.

Comment: Looks like this is the fix. Thanks!